# Google cloud function - stored procedure is not running

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a function running on google cloud that process an HTTP POST request from [JOTFORM](https://www.jotform.com/help/245-How-to-Setup-a-Webhook-with-JotForm) and a stored procedure that gets JSON and insert the data into mysql table.
When I try to run the stored procedure fron mysql server - it works fine, The problem is when I try to run it from Google cloud function using node.js -No data insert into table.

Here is the section from google function :

```
const mySQL = require('mysql');
const config = require('./config.json');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const instanceConnectionName = process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME || config.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME ;
const dbUser = process.env.SQL_USER || config.MYSQL_USER;  
const dbPassword = process.env.SQL_PASSWORD || config.MYSQL_PASSWORD;  
const dbName = process.env.SQL_DB_NAME || config.SQL_DB_NAME ;  
const mysqlPort = process.env.PORT || config.PORT;

// [START functions_sql_mysql]
const mysqlConfig = {
  connectionLimit: 1,
  user: dbUser,
  password: dbPassword,
  database: dbName,
  port : mysqlPort
};
 mysqlConfig.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${instanceConnectionName}`;
 exports.GetWebHookJotContent = (req, res) => {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function(responses) {

      if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        const error = new Error('Only POST requests are accepted');
        error.code = 405;
        throw error;
      }
      const events = req.body || [];   
      let mysqlPool ;

    if (!mysqlPool) {
      mysqlPool = mySQL.createPool(mysqlConfig);
   }

   mysqlPool.query('CALL `fichman`.`sp_insert_Submission` (' + events + ')');

  })
  .then(() => res.status(200).end())
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(err.code || 500).send(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
}
```

How can I debug it and see what `events` contains?
Can you figure out what can be the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal example that doesn't work the way you want (not just a snippet).  You could be doing something else wrong that's not shown here.

Comment: The way you're dealing with promises doesn't look correct to me at all.

Comment: So, you haven't passed a callback to mysqlPool.query(), and you haven't promisified the client.  So I'm guessing what is happening is that, even if the query starts working, as soon as the next portion of your promise chain sets res.status(), the function exits and kills the request to the SQL server.  You can probably add a console.log() statement after the query (maybe even logging the event object, as you asked) and see if this is indeed going on.